# How to combine a tuple's two integer values into one for storage in a Hashset?

Tags: c#, tuples, hashset

I have two methods like this

```
HashSet<Tuple<int,int>> _xyPairs = new HashSet<Tuple<int,int>>();
private void SetTravelled(int x, int y, bool travelled)
{
    var t = new Tuple<int, int>(x, y);

    if (travelled)
        _xyPairs.Add(t);
    else
        _xyPairs.Remove(t);
}

private bool HaveTravelled(int x, int y)
{
    return _xyPairs.Contains(new Tuple<int, int>(x, y));
}
```

I don't mind the first method so much because it's not called very often. The second method however is called very frequently. So I have to create new Tuple's over and over.

Is there a way to combine the two integers into one value for the Hashset?

Comment: Are the two integers related mathematically? What is their typical range?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an indication that the tuple is actually causing you a problem, you could try to combine the two 32-bit integers into one 64-bit integer:

```
HashSet<long> _xyPairs = new HashSet<long>();

private void SetTravelled(int x, int y, bool travelled)
{
    var t = Combine(x, y)
    ...

private bool HaveTravelled(int x, int y)
{
    return _xyPairs.Contains(Combine(x, y));
}

private static long Combine(int x, int y)
{
    return (long)(((ulong)x) | ((ulong)y) << 32);
}
```

Comment: (Yes, combining two `Int32` into one `Int64` is hard. A cleaner solution is defining a custom `struct Pair : IEquatable<Pair>`.)

Comment: @dtd Why not a simple _KeyValuePair<int, int>_?

Comment: @CédricBignon That's not really any better than `Tuple<int, int>`, which the OP already rejected.

Comment: @Brian The key difference is that `KeyValuePair<int, int>` is a struct.  Since it's a value type, it's functionally equivalent to packing it into an `Int64` (also a value type of the same size), but you don't have to write any of the bit manipulation code yourself.

Comment: @CédricBignon The problem I see with `KeyValuePair` is that it's probably semantically not correct -- it just happens to have two ints in it.  Something more like `System.Drawing.Point` or a custom struct would be more semantically appropriate, IMO.